# No data exists for the row/column

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc, mdac

While executing the following code in ASP.NET with C#, I am getting an exception like "No data exists for the row/column."

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new   OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStr"]);        
DbConnection.Close();        
string cmdText = "SELECT Team_ID FROM team_details WHERE Team_Code=?";        
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, DbConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("?Code", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = tbCode.Text;
DbConnection.Open();
OdbcDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DR.Read();        
if (DR.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value)        
{
    args.IsValid = false;
}
else
{
    args.IsValid = true;
}
DbConnection.Close();
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and MySQL. I'm using MySql ODBC connector 5.1 and MDAC2.8.

Please guide me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Read method returns a boolean indicating whether any rows were returned or not, so you should always test this value prior to accessing the result of the reader.

```
  OdbcDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();



if (DR.Read() && DR.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value)    
 {   
    args.IsValid = false; 
 } 
 else 
 {   
     args.IsValid = true; 
 } 
 DbConnection.Close();
```

EDIT ---- 
You should also consider `using` the connections since this will ensure that is is closed (disposed) even though an exception occurs inside the using statement.

You could also get rid of the `if` statement, but that is a matter of taste.

Finally standard .NET idiom would be to keep the connection string in the ConnectionStrings section of the web.config. This is not shown below.

```
   using(OdbcConnection DbConnection = new  OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStr"]))
   {
          string cmdText = "SELECT Team_ID FROM team_details WHERE Team_Code=?";        
          OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, DbConnection);
          cmd.Parameters.Add("?Code", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = tbCode.Text;
          DbConnection.Open();
          OdbcDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          args.IsValid = DR.Read() && DR.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value;
   }
```

Comment: thanks very much, it's working fine. I'm new comer in Asp.net.

Comment: You are more than welcome. I have added a suggestion about using in an edit. Feel free to neglect it :)

Comment: I got your point, I will use it, thanks a lot for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 4):

After going through so much trouble with this error I discovered something hidden about it:

I declared a connection object as a public variable. I then use it through several functions, and at one point I decided not to reset its connection string since it was already set by a preceding procedure.

The subsequent function, which called the previous function while in a loop through a table set by the public connection object thus lost its connection after the previous function returned its values,  and CLOSED ITS CONNECTION OBJECT (which is a public object shared by the two functions)!

I hope that made sense... it took me hours to be able to figure out what was going on.